# For the 5th edition, what Eberron-like official settings exist?

Tags: dnd-5e, campaign-settings

I want to set my campaign in a fantasy world with these attributes:

- high-level magic is nearly impossible and very rare
- on the other hand, low-level everyday magic is common and well-known
- non-mages can use magic my means of devices, not artifacts
- these devices are steampunk-ish clockworks, driven by mystical energy

Does any official setting suit? I was thinking about Eberron, but it seems [there are no related products for 5e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Eberron_modules_and_sourcebooks).

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, [not posting small or incomplete answers](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/6534), especially when a question is on hold.

Comment: For whomever VtC, this does not look like a shopping question.  This is very much a "previous edition had X, is it in edition Y?  If so, where?"

Comment: @Wesley Related links are to literally link our site's questions into a meaningful web of related questions. Related links that are given in the sense of "reading this would (help) solve your problem" aren't useful in comments and get deleted. As a rule of thumb, if a comment is trying to help solve the problem, it shouldn't be a comment. So "You can look at [thing] for ideas…" shouldn't be a comment, it should be the start of an answer (if anything).

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to wait for WotC to publish an Eberron adventurer’s guide (*Five Nations Adventurer’s Guide*, if you will) as they’ve done for *[Sword Coast](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/sc-adventurers-guide)*, to play an Eberron game in 5e.

Just run [5e in Eberron](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Eberron_v1.pdf), and have the world behave how you envisage. You may want to stop at level progression at around 10th level (or whenever you decide that the spells are **too high level now**).

Comment: The problem is, the spell level is an abstraction which is relevant in term of the assumed setting. For instance, a spell that can return people from dead is definitely high-level, despite the druidic Reincarnate is only 5-level spell. For a different setting, a total spell list overhaul might be needed, hence the question. UA actually doesn't contain any reworks, only additions.

Answer (score 4):

As someone pointed out in a comment up above, D&D is inherently high magic. Virtually all of the official D&D game settings are high fantasy/high magic, with the exception of maybe Dark Sun, but Dark Sun hasn't been ported to 5e yet.

I recommend you either homebrew your own setting and impose limitation on magic, or alternatively, find a game system and setting that more suits your needs.

These aren't D&D 5e game setting, but completely different game systems which may provide more of what you're looking for. If you're just going to completely overhaul the D&D magic system and rewrite all the magic classes in the game, maybe you should ask yourself why you're thinking about using D&D 5e in the first place.

Try [The Burning Wheel](https://www.burningwheel.com/), the game assumes no magic from the start, and if you want magic, you can add it on, and have as much or as little as possible. There are many different types of magic system in the game as well.

Alternately, try [FATE](http://www.faterpg.com/), again here magic is an add-on to the basic setting, you can have as little or as much magic as you want.

If you're set on running a D&D 5e campaign, be prepared to do a lot of work up-front to limit the magic in your setting. You'll have to modify most races and classes, or ban them outright. You'll have to put a blanket ban on magic levels, such as keeping wizards to 3rd level spells and below, which will make the magic using classes unattractive to play since their progression will be nerfed, so you'll need to come up with rules to take that into account if you don't go the route of banning them completely.

Comment: @fiend The question has been significantly modified from its original form, and your answer no longer applies.  To prevent attracting downvotes, I recommend you either update your answer to address the new question, or delete your current answer outright, once the question is reopened.

Comment: Both the comment that incited it, and your first sentence, are overstatements.  I've run D&D campaigns from "magic is really hard to find" to Monty Haul.  D&D 5e can accommodate low magic settings (magic is rare, but it is still powerful, which was GG's original concept of D&D magic anyway) due to its bounded accuracy model.  The DMG has some guidelines for world customization that you might want to refer to in your answer.  There is only as much magic in the world as the DM allows.